# Query does not insert into database

Tags: php, mysql

I've made this code but for some reason when i submit the form the data is not inserted to the table name posts. here's my code, i might have a typo or something, it'd be great if someone could have a look.

```
$fnames = Array("","","","","");

$fcnt = 0;

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 

    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "pjpeg", "x=png","png",); 

    // do all 5 files!  
    for ( $fnum = 1; $fnum <= 5; ++$fnum )
    {
        $curfile = $_FILES["uploaded_file" . $fnum];
        if ($curfile["error"] > 0) { 
            echo "Return Code: " . $curfile["error"] . "<br>\n"; 
        } else { 
            $ftype = explode( "/", $curfile["type"])[1]; // get the part after the /
            $fsize = $curfile["size"];
            if ( in_array($ftype, $allowedExts) && $fsize < 20000000 ) 
            {
                echo "Upload: " . $curfile["name"] . "<br>\n"; 
                echo "Type: " . $ftype . "<br>\n"; 
                echo "Size: " . ($fsize/1024) . " KB<br>\n"; 
                echo "Temp file: " . $curfile["tmp_name"] . "<br>\n"; 
                $fname = $_SESSION["userid"] . "_" . $curfile["name"];
                if (file_exists("uploads/$fname"))
                { 
                    echo "$fname already exists.<br>\n"; 
                } else { 
                    move_uploaded_file($curfile["tmp_name"], "uploads/$fname");
                    $fnames[$fnum-1] = $fname;
                    ++$fcnt;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                echo "No valid file in slot $fnum<br>\n";
            }           
        }
    }
    if ( $fcnt > 1 ) 
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO posts (picture1, picture2, picture3, picture4, picture5) VALUES( ". "'" . implode("','", $fnames) . "')";
        echo "DEBUG SQL: $sql <hr>\n";
        mysqli_query($sql);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoops, sorry, the beginning is a part of the code too. :/

Comment: Stop guessing. What does *error* is reported? Also, use parameterized queries (as that could very easily be the source of the problem).

Comment: Code is so messy. You can spot errors way faster and easier if you cleanup the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a quick glance:

A) error in your `mysqli_query($sql);`.
The mysqli_ extensin needs the connection pointer, something like: `mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);`

B) Also, modify your query to look like `mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbConn));`. It will show you the sql errors, if any.

**EDIT 1**
If no errors appear after you put the mysqli_error(), then i think your script never gets to the sql part. Something stops it before that if.
Put on top of your script:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

and check if any php errors appear on the page.

Comment: I've tried that already, changed it right now. still nothing :/ the echo SQL looks just fine, echos all the value correctly, just doesn't store them

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your fields count and values count are the same. Also correct this as well:

```
"'".implode("','", $fnames)."'"
```

in values passed.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time is a string/integer mismatch. Double check all your string escape characters. Copy your final query string and use some external tool to submit the query. You could start hardcoding all your data in the query and then proceed by adding one parameter at a time. Eventually you'll find the field (or fields) that causes the problem.

However, read carefully the error message first instead of guessing blindly what's causing the problem :-)